# while loop android

Tags: android

This is part of my code which vibrate for the random amount of time.

```
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {            
    SharedPreferences appSettings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);        
    boolean doVibration = appSettings.getBoolean("vibrationCue", true);      

    // determine whether estimation or cue mode is active        
    if (!currentlyEstimating) {          
        if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {      
            Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);         
            // determine random timespan for cue(s)          
            initCueLength();          
            if (doVibration)             
            {             
                loopnum = 0;         
                while(loopnum < 5) {           
                     v.vibrate(cueLength);         
                    loopnum ++;         
                }         
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want the vibration to repeat for example for five time. But the while loop doesn't work. Can you guide me that what can be a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `v.vibrate` works asynchronous, i.e. doesn't wait for the specified time, so those 5 calls happen almost instantly and have the same effect like one call.

To get the desired effect, define a vibration pattern:

http://android.konreu.com/developer-how-to/vibration-examples-for-android-phone-development/